# Why C++ async run sequentially without future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async,[] {std::cout << "async..." << std::endl; while (1);});
    std::cout << "runing main..." << std::endl;
}
```

In this code, only "async..." will be outputted, which means the code is blocked at async. However, if I add future and let the statement become:

```
std::future<bool> fut = std::async([] 
{std::cout << "async..." << std::endl; while (1); return false; });
```

Then everything runs smoothly (it will not be blocked). I am not sure why it happen in this way. I think async is supposed to run in a separate thread.

Comment: Please also note that async doesn't guarantee to start a new thread. I can be [lazy](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2889.html#Lazy).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`encppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

> If the `std::future` obtained from `std::async` is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the `std::future` will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code such as the following synchronous:
>
> ```
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
> ```

If I did get that right, it comes from these parts of the standard (N4527):

*§30.6.6 [futures.unique_future]:*

> `~future();`
>
> Effects:
>
> — releases any shared state (30.6.4);

*§30.6.4#5 [futures.state]* (emphasis is mine):

> When an asynchronous return object or an asynchronous provider is said to release its shared state, it means:
>
> [...].
>
> — these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, **except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state**.

Since you did not store the result of your first `std::async` call, the destructor of `std::future` is called and since all 3 conditions are met:

- the `std::future` was created via `std::async`;
- the shared state is not yet ready (due to your infinite loop);
- there is no remaining reference to this future

...then the call is blocking.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I am looking for.