# Calling std::async function inside a synchronous function in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, stdasync

Consider following examples:

**1. All functions are called asynchronously**

```cpp
void threadFunc()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "thread working..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}

void middleFunc()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, threadFunc);
    std::cout << "humble\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, middleFunc); // this special line
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "main working..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and output comes as

```
main working..
humble
other working..
main working..
other working..
main working..
```

**2. First function is called synchronously, and second is called asynchronously**

if I replace async call in main with a normal function call, like so:

```cpp
int main()
{
    middleFunc(); // this special line
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "main working..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

then only middleFunc() & threadFunc() run, execution never reaches main()'s while loop, and output comes as

```
humble
other working..
other working..
other working..
other working..
```

---

**In both the cases threadFunc() runs with std::async. So, as soon as middleFunc() prints 'humble' shouldn't it return back to main() ?**

Comment: `async` isn't as asynchronous as you may think it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816928/why-c-async-run-sequentially-without-future

Comment: If you don't do something with the `std::future` that's returned by `std::async` then the call will block until the future's destructor finishes, which requires that the function called by `async` finishes. Save your `std::future`.

Comment: thanks @hlt and @François Andrieux 

I added a global variable `std::future<void> globalFuture;` , which is getting the future returned by `middleFunc()` 's `std::async`. Now everything works asynchronously.